# Using vanilla JavaScript, is it possible to add a DOM element and fade in using CSS transition, without using setTimeout or CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to add an element to the page, but have it fade it, without using `setTimeout()`?

I am thinking that for CSS transition, it has to first have a value (opacity 0), and then, let it have another value (opacity 1), so that the transition can occur, so a `setTimeout()` is needed.

The snippet below can add the new row, but is it possible to make it fade in, again, not using jQuery's `fadeIn()`, `setTimeout()`, or CSS animation?  Is it possible to do it using CSS transition delay?

```js
const tableElement = document.querySelector("#tbl");

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  tableElement.innerHTML = `${tableElement.innerHTML}<tr><td>Hi There ${Math.random()}</td></tr>`;
});
```

```css
tr {
  transition: all 1s
}

tr {
  opacity: 0.2
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

Comment: Why the restrictions?

Comment: you could look to how jquery controls it with the manual css animations in javascript

Comment: Yea, seriously, browsers support all those things, why not use the facilities available?

Comment: because `setTimeout()` is a bit messy.  I'd like to have it done "all in one shot"... kind of way

Comment: Then use CSS animation

Comment: there isn't a all one shot - you have to do it with some timer mechanism

Comment: RequestAnimationFrame perhaps

Comment: I am asking "Is it possible"... so I am asking technically, using CSS transition delay, or some other mechanism, is it possible.  So it is a valid technical question

Comment: What's the difference between "CSS animation" and "CSS transition delay"?

Comment: that's because using CSS animation, you have to use keyframe, and some older browser may not support it

Comment: Maybe this will help you - [fadeIn](https://gist.github.com/chrisbuttery/cf34533cbb30c95ff155)

Comment: Well what you could do is add the element, then (I know, I know) set a timeout or `requestAnimationFrame()` or `Promise.resolve()` to add a class to the target element that triggers a transition.

Comment: what old browser doesn't support keyframes?

Comment: @nonopolarity tbh. dont worry to much about "older" browser. https://caniuse.com/?search=keyframes We are in the year 2021. HTML5/CSS3 is the way to go.

Comment: well... I mean, that's true... when I look at keyframe, I am looking at it from the perspective of 2013 / 2014 time frame... so things might have changed... I guess perhaps some 7 year old Android phone, some particular browser on it, may not support it, or something

Comment: The thing is that CSS transitions happen when things about an element *change*. When you add a brand new element, it's the way it is from the moment of its "birth".  That's why letting a render happen followed by a change to the element's nature (like, adding a class) is probably necessary.

Comment: If you *really* want to support old browsers, then `setTimeout()` is probably the safest approach, because that's been supported for over 20 years.

Comment: yes, that's what I am getting at, just that perhaps there is some really neat trick to get it done that I am not aware of... but I guess if most people say it is not possible, then it is not possible, unless if @Bergi come up with a method when he sees it

Comment: it's still early to say impossible ;) let's wait more ... I believe in CSS magic

Answer (score 2):

fadeIn without setTimeout and css animation ;)

```js
const tableElement = document.querySelector('#tbl');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  tableElement.innerHTML = `${tableElement.innerHTML}<tr><td class='hidden'>Hi There ${Math.random()}</td></tr>`;

  const el = document.querySelector('.hidden');
  el.classList.remove('hidden');
  fadeIn(el);
});



function fadeIn(el, display) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.display = display || 'block';

  (function fade() {
    let val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
    let proceed = !(((val += 0.04) > 1));

    if (parseInt(el.style.opacity) === 1) {
      btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
    if (proceed) {
      el.style.opacity = val;
      requestAnimationFrame(fade);
    }
  })();
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

Comment: using `requestAnimationFrame`... it is more complicated than using `setTimeout()` but worth learning I think

Comment: That's right, it's more complicated to use `requestAnimationFrame`. Such a curiosity from `setTimeout()` take a look - [JavaScript counters the hard way - HTTP 203](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCi6AZMkxcU&t=158s)

Comment: that's a pretty complicated solution there... I suspect it is getting down to the level of, if there is a company that plans to only make a hardware counters, and be able to use it 50 hours vs 12 is an issue or something like that